# Две гугл карты на одной странице

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Добрый день! Сделал черно-белую гугл-карту со свом маркером,нужно было сделать вторую,но две карты не показываются, у второй карты виден только маркер и значок гугл внизу.

Что я делаю не так и как исправить? вот код

```js
 <link rel="nofollow" href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>  
<script> 
 
var map,map2;
var vladimir = new google.maps.LatLng(56.1495019, 40.3827949);
var msk = new google.maps.LatLng(56.1495019, 40.3827949);
 
var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'mystyle'; 
    
 
 
function initialize() {
 
  var stylez =  [
  {
      "stylers": [
      { "saturation": -100 },
      { "gamma": 1.5 }
    ]
  },{
  }
]
  
 
  
 
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: vladimir,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
  };
    
    var mapOptions2 = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: msk,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
  };
    
      
 
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);
    
   map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"),
      mapOptions2); 
    
 
 
  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: "Мой стиль"
  };
 
    
      
  
    var image = 'assets/images/maker.png';
 
    
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  
    map: map,
    position: vladimir,
    title: 'Hello World!',
    icon: image
  });
    
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
  
    map: map2,
    position: msk,
    title: 'Hello World!',
    icon: image
  });   
    
 
  var jayzMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(stylez, styledMapOptions);
 
 
 map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, jayzMapType);
 map2.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, jayzMapType); 
    
}
</script>
```

```html
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 650px; height: 320px;"></div> 
 <div id="map_canvas2" style="width: 650px; height: 320px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="map1" style="width:500px;height:500px"></div>
        <div id="map2" style="width:500px;height:500px"></div>

        <script>
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map1");
            var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.2), zoom: 10
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);


            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map2");
            var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.2), zoom: 10
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Насчёт чёрно-белой, я не знаю.

Comment: Можно для чёрно-белой фильтр поставить